# Downloading Feature like Amazon Prime Video App in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

Does anyone have an idea about the approach using in amazon prime video app downloading feature?

Amazon prime added next video in the queue when try to download 2nd video, if we start downloading the 2nd video then the first video automatically moves to queue state with downloading percentage. So my question is how they maintain this hierarchy? I have to give HLS support in my app for offline play as well. I tried this Apple Link for my task and able to download single video and play offline but not understand how to add the next video in the queue and maintain the hierarchy.

**2 Videos for download 2nd in queue**

[image: 2 Videos for download 2nd in queue]

**When I start download for second video it  enters the first video in queue**

[image: When I start download for second video it enters the first video in queue...]

I tried this : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are asking about the queuing mechanism used for video download in this Amazon app. Are you trying to understand how they pause the current video download when a user tries to start a new video download and resumes the download of the previous video after the new video download gets completed?

Comment: @AravindBhuvanendran I am not understanding exactly what they are doing, I think I have to use DispatchWorkGroup, But I was stuck on point to pause/resume/cancel particular video to get particular AVAssetDownloadTask...If you have any idea or sample code for managing this please share here or on my email sumitkapoor2511@gmail.com Thanks!

Comment: @AravindBhuvanendran if you have any idea about this please let me know as I am stuck on this to do in proper way Thanks....